# pythonscript not compiling with pdflatex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pdflatex

I am having problems with running Pdflatex from a Python script (python 3 on Mac Catalina). It used to work but might have stopped working since the latest OS update. The problem only arises when I try to run the code from Jupyter Notebook, it works fine in a shell. Here is a MWE:

```
import os, subprocess, sys

def create_latex(number):
    latex = "\\documentclass{standalone}\\begin{document} test $%s$" %(number)
    latex += "\\end{document}"
    f = open("test" + ".tex", "w")
    f.write(latex)
    f.close()
    os.system("pdflatex " + "test" + ".tex")
    os.system("open " + "test" + ".pdf")
    return None
```

There is no error, the .tex file gets created but not compiled so the pdf does not open. I am very confused by this...